# C, MPI variable scope

Tags: c, mpi

I'm looking at someone else's MPI code and there are a number of times that variables are declared in `main()` and used in other functions (some MPI specific). I am new to MPI, but in my programming experience that is normally not supposed to be done. Basically it is difficult for me to determine if it is safe to do this (no errors are thrown).

The entire code is quite long so I will just give a simplified version below:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // ...unrelated code
    int num_procs, local_rank, name_len;
    MPI_Comm comm_new;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(proc_name, &name_len);

    create_ring_topology(&comm_new, &local_rank, &num_procs);
    // ...unrelated code

    MPI_Comm_free(&comm_new);
    MPI_Finalize();
}

void create_ring_topology(MPI_Comm* comm_new, int* local_rank, int* num_procs) {    
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs);

    int dims[1], periods[1];
    int dimension = 1;
    dims[0] = *num_procs;
    periods[0] = 1;
    int* local_coords = malloc(sizeof(int)*dimension);

    MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, dimension, dims, periods, 0, comm_new);
    MPI_Comm_rank(*comm_new, local_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(*comm_new, num_procs);
    MPI_Cart_coords(*comm_new, *local_rank, dimension, local_coords);
    sprintf(s_local_coords, "[%d]", local_coords[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just regular pointer usage. Nothing wrong with that.

The variables are declared in `main` and remain in-scope until `main` returns, i.e. almost for the duration of the program.

Note that MPI does not actually add anything to C. All it is is an extra library. It does not extend the language.

Comment: Ah, that bit of information was what I was missing. So something referenced that was declared in main in always safe? I don't really know the rules on how the address space is shared among different processes

Comment: Almost always. If you use `atexit()` you could have code run after main returns, so any variable declared in main would be out of scope and hence unsafe.

Comment: Ok, yeah I'm not going to be doing anything like that, thanks

Comment: But in this case `create_ring_topology` is just using the pointers that were passed to it, so the caller, i.e. `main` has to ensure they're safe. They are.

Comment: @asimes: MPI processes do not share any address space. Each process has its own memory space, with its own copy of each variable declared.

Comment: @suszterpatt, if one process were to overflow very badly (I'm not worried about it in this code, theoretically) could it affect the other processes?

Comment: @asimes no. They're separate processes as far as the OS is concerned, so they have their own virtual memory space.

Comment: @asimes: Define "overflow", and define "affect". :) If one process crashes (e.g. due to overflowing the stack), it'll crash your entire MPI application, other processes included. Plain old high memory usage on one process won't make other processes run out of memory faster, though it may still decrease their performance (e.g. if they share the same hard drive for paging).

Comment: I guess I meant if you have one processor running multiple "virtual processors"

Comment: @asimes Only in the sense that your Firefox can affect your Skype. It can compete for memory, it can compete for CPU, but it can't directly meddle with the other process. The only exception is that if one MPI process crashes then the others will also either crash or more likely just freeze.

Comment: Also the MPI terminology is that each rank is a `process`, **not** a processor. Even if you only have one process per processor. It's also perfectly valid to have more than one process per processor. That's called over subscription and it has legitimate uses sometimes.